# How to insert curent datetime using specific format

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `post` text NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table created

```
INSERT INTO `posts` ( 'user', 'post', 'date') VALUES
('she', 'dolphin', '???');
('me', 'chandra'), '???');
```

Instead of `???` I need current datetime in the following format:`day.month. hour:min`

For example for today and now: `03.01. 00:34`

Comment: Why not just store the datetime datatype?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a `DATETIME` column type? Then you could just do `('she','dolphin', NOW())` ?

Comment: If possible, it would be better to update the database to use datetime storage for efficiency.

Comment: @MitchDempsey, I tried your solution and got `#1054 - Unknown column 'she' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That a bad idea, because you are storing the data

- in a format that can't be ordered
- in a format that mySQL can't optimize in any  meaningful way
- without the year of the date

Use a proper mySQL [`DATETIME` field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) instead, and format the output using [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) when you make the query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%d.%m. %H:%i") FROM `posts`;
```